# Sharing a video with a caption using Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the latest version of the Facebook SDK.

Sharing a photo with a caption is easy:

```
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:image userGenerated:YES];
photo.caption = txt_desc.text;
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:nil];
```

But the .caption property is not found on FBSDKShareVideo or FBSDKShareVideoContent. I have gone down the list for all the properties available to FBSDKShareVideo and FBSDKShareVideoContent but there's nothing that seems like it would hold the caption. The FB SDK documentation doesn't give any answers either.

I know it's possible to share a video with a caption on iOS because the Instagram iOS app does it. I just don't know how. Any one have any idea?

Comment: _“because the Instagram iOS app does it”_ – that doesn’t mean anything; Instagram is owned by Facebook, and as such their apps can have additional capabilities, that normal, 3rd-party apps don’t get.

Comment: Fairly sure video sharing on FB was working before FB acquired instagram. But not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareVideo/) for `FBSDKShareVideo`, it does not support providing a description/caption.

Comment: It's silly that it doesn't tbh. Videos on facebook have captions just like photos. I guess I'll wait for Facebook to change the SDK.

Comment: That's your only option at the moment ;)